# How is this a tangent vector?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, tangent-bundle

Let $\pi :E\to M$ be a vector bundle with typical fiber $V$. Suppose that $\pi^*E$ is the pullback bundle of $E$ by $\pi$. If $(\zeta, \xi) \in \pi^*E$, then the map $\pi(\zeta +t\xi)$ is constant in $t$, because both $\zeta$ and $\xi$ are in the same fiber, call it $E_p$. In my textbook (*Differential Geometric Structures* by Poor), it is said that the map $\mathcal J:\pi^*E\to TE$ given by $$\mathcal J(\zeta +t\xi) = \frac d{dt}\Big|_{t=0}(\zeta +t\xi)$$ actually maps into the vertical bundle $\mathcal VE$. My questions are:

1. How is $\frac d{dt}\Big|_{t =0} (\zeta + t\xi) \in TE$? And
2. How is it in $\mathcal VE$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you noted, the elements of $\pi^*E$ are exactly the pairs $(\zeta,\xi)\in E_p\times E_p$ for some point $p\in M$.

Thus, for any $(\zeta,\xi)\in \pi^*E$ the image of the curve $\gamma:\Bbb R\to E,\ \ t\mapsto \zeta+t\xi\ $ lies fully in the fiber $E_p$ (where $p=\pi(\zeta)=\pi(\xi)$). 
So, $\pi(\gamma(t))=p$ is constant, therefore
$$d(\pi\circ\gamma)\,(0)\ =\ d\pi\,d\gamma\,(0) = 0\,,$$
i.e. the differential (speed vector) of $\gamma$ at $t=0$ (or at any $t$ actually) will be in the vertical bundle $\mathcal V_pE\,\subseteq T_pE\,\subseteq TE\ $ (and can be naturally identified with $\xi\in E_p$, by the way).

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: By $d\gamma (0)$, do you mean $\gamma_*(\frac d {dt}_{t=0})$? Also, what is the reason for the above mentioned natural identification?

Comment: Yes, it's the same. Actually, $\gamma$ can be viewed as a map of manifolds, so we can take its differential (and also identify $\Bbb R$ with $T_0\Bbb R$).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying!